Maximizing Edge Weights in Planar Graphs with Vertex Weights Summing to One
Let $G$ be a planar graph where we assign a non-negative real number to every vertex
of $G$ such that the sum of these numbers is $1$. Then, we assign to every edge the product of the numbers at the two endpoints of that edge. Prove that the sum of the numbers at the edges is at most $\frac{3}{8}$.
I have been stucked on this problem for quite some time now. Any help would be great.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1418618p7980847

Ignoring the planar condition, the worst-case is the complete graph, where we can say
$$\sum x_i x_j = \frac{(\sum x_i)^2 - \sum x_i^2}{2}$$
I believe $\sum x_i^2$ is minimized when $x_i$ are all equal. Then we can say,
$$\sum x_i x_j \leq \frac{1 - \sum (1/n)^2}{2} = \frac{n-1}{2n}$$
Which is interestingly $3/8$ for $n=4$. Though I'm not sure how to apply the planarity property to derive the desired answer.

Planarity implies that the number of edges (the number of terms in the sum of products) is at most $3n-6$ rather than $n(n-1)/2$.

For a fixed set of vertices, the more edges you have, the better (every edge makes a positive contribution to the total). So the complete graph is the best case.

To the person who gave a negative vote: I agree that this isn't a complete solution. If there's something actually wrong with the mathematics, let me know. Otherwise, behavior like that discourages contributions and keeps discussions in the comments. Moreover, the OP specifically asked for any help. So even an attempt at a solution should be fine as long as it's relevant and has some contribution to the problem

I like this question! Here's a cheesy way to do it (warning: you might not like the solution). Let $w(G)$ be the sum of all edge weights of the graph. Let $w(v)$ be the weight of a vertex $v \in V(G)$, and let $w(e)$ be the weight of an edge.
Lemma: Let $A \subseteq V(G)$ be an independent set of the graph. Let $G'$ be a graph obtained from $G$ by identifying all vertices of $A$ into a new vertex, say $v$, so that the neighbors of $v \in V(G')$  (in $G'$) is $\bigcup_{a \in A} N_G(a)$. Put the weight of $v \in V(G)$ as $\sum_{a \in A} w(a)$. Then $w(G) \leq w(G')$.
Proof. Let  $\bigcup_{a \in A} N_G(a) = \{n_1, \dots, n_p\}:=N$. Write $A = \{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$. Observe that the operation described above loses at most
$$
w(a_1) (w(n_1) + \dots + w(n_p)) + \dots + w(a_k) (w(n_1) + \dots + w(n_p)) = \left(\sum_{a \in A} w(a)\right) \left(\sum_{n \in N} w(n)\right) 
$$
weight, but gains precisely the latter term as the weight.
Lemma: For $n \leq 4$, the number $3/8$ is best.
Proof. For a graph on $n$ vertices, let $w_i:= w(v_i)$ be the weight of vertex $i$. Now, for a vertex, if we sum up the weights of all edges adjacent to it, we have
$$
\sum_{e \sim v_i} w(e) \leq w_i (1- w_i).
$$
This means that
$$
2w(G) \leq \sum_{i} w_i (1- w_i) = 1 - \left(\sum_i w_i^2\right).
$$
We wish to minimise $\left(\sum_i w_i^2\right)$, subject to $\sum_{i} w_i = 1$. This occurs precisely when $w_i = 1/n$ for all $i$.  So for any graph:
$$
w(G) \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n}.
$$
The last quantity is $\leq 3/8$ when $n \leq 4$.

Now for the punchline: the solution follows from the fact that any planar graph is $4$-colorable.
